# PrettyFaces: make all jsf pages "extension-less"

Tags: jsf-2, prettyfaces

I would like to write inside that code (pretty-config.xml):

```
<pretty-config xmlns="http://ocpsoft.com/prettyfaces/3.3.2" 
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
               xsi:schemaLocation="http://ocpsoft.com/prettyfaces/3.3.2
                                        http://ocpsoft.com/xml/ns/prettyfaces/ocpsoft-pretty-faces-3.3.2.xsd">

 <!--- ??? --->

</pretty-config>
```

for simply having all my pages mapped to ".jsf / .xhtml".

/admin/listusers => /admin/listusers.jsf

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for this you have several options that I can think of off the top of my head, unless you want to map all URLs in your application using the traditional PrettyFaces mappings...

You can either use a PrettyFaces  rule, using something like this:

```
<pretty-config xmlns="http://ocpsoft.com/prettyfaces/3.3.2" 
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://ocpsoft.com/prettyfaces/3.3.2
                                    http://ocpsoft.com/xml/ns/prettyfaces/ocpsoft-pretty-faces-3.3.2.xsd">

    <rewrite match="(?!.*.jsf.*)(.*)" substitute="$1.jsf" outbound="false" inbound="true"/>
    <rewrite match="(.*).jsf" substitute="$1" inbound="false" outbound="true" />

</pretty-config>
```

But this gets complicated since you actually need two rules, so you could also use http://ocpsoft.org/rewrite/ for this as well, and things would be a little simpler and more declarative:

```
ConfigurationBuilder.begin()
  .addRule(Join.path("/{p}").to("/{p.jsf}").where("p").matches("(?!*.jsf).*"));
```

The traditional PrettyFaces approach would be to map a URL to each page using url-mapping declarations in the config:

```
<pretty-config xmlns="http://ocpsoft.com/prettyfaces/3.3.2" 
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://ocpsoft.com/prettyfaces/3.3.2
                                    http://ocpsoft.com/xml/ns/prettyfaces/ocpsoft-pretty-faces-3.3.2.xsd">

    <url-mapping id="listUsers">
        <pattern value="/admin/listusers"/>
        <view-id value="/admin/listusers.jsf" />
    </url-mapping>


    <url-mapping id="login">
        <pattern value="/login"/>
        <view-id value="/login.jsf" />
    </url-mapping>

</pretty-config>
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

PrettyFaces is pretty powerful for all kinds of rewriting scenarios.

When it only concerns extension-less urls, OmnniFaces is an interesting alternative. You can have extension-less urls with no configuration at all by putting your pages in a special directory, or have a little configuration in web.xml:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.omnifaces.FACES_VIEWS_SCAN_PATHS</param-name>
    <param-value>/*.xhtml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

See the [package documentation](http://omnifaces.org/docs/javadoc/current/org/omnifaces/facesviews/package-summary.html) for more info.